# Remove Space from Particular line In Textfile Python

Tags: python, text-files

I have textfiles that have the date stored on line 7 of each file, formatted as such:

```
    Date:  1233PM 14 MAY 00
```

I would like to search through each file and get the new line 7 to be formatted as such:

```
    Date:  1233PM 14 MAY 2000
```

So, basically, I just need to stick a '20' in front of the last two digits in line seven.

Probably not the most difficult problem, but I have been having difficulty as textfile.readlines() reads everything into the first (textfile[0]) position.

Comment: what do you mean while saying "textfile.readlines() reads everything into the first (textfile[0]) position." Give us a sample from your file and/or your code to understand what is your problem here

Comment: when I do : infile = open('file.txt','r') and then try to do a simple print[7] it is out of range because the open command reads the entire textfile into the first line position.

Comment: can you copy part of text from your file and put it in your question?

Comment: If you have several files that need similar replacement, you should be using `sed`, `awk` or similar tool.

Comment: The text file is one long run-on in NotePad, but looks nicely formatted in NotePad++ or Wordpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all the file, change the specified line then save it again:

```
arc = open('file_name.txt').readlines()[0].split('\r')

#Do what you want with the 7th line i.e. arc[6]

new_arc = open('file_name.txt','w')
for line in arc:
    new_arc.write(line)
    new_arc.write('\n')

new_arc.close()
```

Comment: This will not work because all lines in the readlines() command are read into the first index, i.e., [0], position.

Comment: @user1951785 ok, but how it is spliting one line from another? It is using \r ?

Comment: Might be...It looks fine in Wordpad or NotePad++, but looks like a funny run-on in Notepad.

Comment: @user1951785 I tried something different and edited the code, so take another look

Comment: Okay, very close now:  TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not list

Comment: @user1951785 where it happened?

Comment: Okay, it appeared to work, but now the formatting of the file is all screwed up.  It looks to now be one long run-on instead of the nice formatting from before.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user1951785, I made an improvement above, please, try again.

Comment: Fernando, is there any way (after the \n) to put those \r spaces back in for processing?

Comment: @user1951785 yes you can use `\r` common in MACs instead of `\n` (common in Unix) or even use `\r\n` (common in windows)

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for your input.  I've tried all three instances, and the progam still says that it is not a properly formatted text file :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# open file
f = open("file.txt" , 'rU+b')
lines = f.readlines()

# modify line 7
lines[6] = lines[6][:-2] + "20" + lines[6][-2:]

# return file pointer to the top so we can rewrite the file
f.seek(0)
f.truncate()

# write the file with new content
f.write(''.join(lines))
f.close
```

Comment: This will not work because all lines in the readlines() command are read into the first index, i.e., [0], position.

Comment: I'm unsure how your lines are being separated. If it's not separated by '\n', what defines a new line in your text file?

Comment: The text file is one long run-on in NotePad, but looks nicely formatted in NotePad++ or Wordpad.

Comment: Okay, Fernando's answer might be sufficient. But you can open the file using 'rU' to include '\r' as newline. Check my edit.

Comment: TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not list

Comment: `for file in os.listdir(inputdir):
        print file
        filin = open(inputdir+file).readlines()[0].split('\r')
        print filin[6]
        filout = open(outdir+file,'wt')
        filin[6] = filin[6][:-2] + "20" + filin[6][-2:]
        filout.write(filin)
        filout.close()
        filin.close()`

Comment: filin is a list. you need to put it into a string. filout.write(''.join(filin))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for idx, line in lines:
        if idx == 7: # or 6
            vals = line.split()
            if len(vals[-1]) == 2:
                vals[-1] = '20'+vals[-1]
            line = ' '.join(vals)
        f.write(line)
```